# rake-pipeline taking a fat dump in the specified output directory how do I stop that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have input location as "assets"; in assets I have various coffeescripts less files etc in varying subfolders

I create an Assetfile job done! something along the lines of

```
require "rake-pipeline-web-filters"
require "rake-pipeline-web-filters/helpers"

output "public"

input "app/assets/javascripts"
match "**/*.coffee" do
 coffee_script
end

## Take all JS inputs and wrap each of them in code to
## register them with the Minispade module loader.
match "**/*.js" do
 minispade :module_id_generator => proc { |input| input.path.sub(/lib\//,    'timelog/').sub(/\.js$/, '') }
 concat "javascripts/app.js"
end

# Take all Less inputs and compile them with Less
input "app/assets/stylesheets"
match "application.css.less" do
  filter(Rake::Pipeline::Web::Filters::TiltFilter) do |input|
    input.sub(/\.less/, '.css')
  end
end
```

Question?

how does one stop the files from the asswets folder being dumped into the output folder ie public?

all kinds of crap is being dumped into the public folder from the assets

Comment: Upvote for best subject line ever. Are you still having trouble? I believe rake-pipeline no longer copying remaining files (fat dump) by default.

Answer (score -2):

Try sprocket gem. It may solve the issue.